# Is bus device communication (e.g. CPU to ethernet) interuptable at any time (state free)?

Tags: assembly, embedded, hardware, interrupt, ethernet

Image the following szenario: On a device with a PIC, a hardware timer cell interrupt triggers a ISR that then sends some data to the ethernet chip. While sending data the PIC arbitrates and forwards a higher interrupt for a different timer cell to the CPU than then triggers an ISR to also write to the same ethernet chip. At no point in time are interrupts masks or even completely disabled.

I understand that all registers will be saved, but:

Does this sort of szenario require any kind of synchronisation? E.g. does the write consist of multiple assembler commands that are not allowed to be interrupted (critical section)? Or are there assmebler commands that handle this as a atomic action, e.g. no interrupt could corruct the data?

Is there maybe even some general design priciple stating that such low level hardware interaction between CPU and bus devices should also be performable in atomic assembler commands that are unaffected by a CPU interrupt?

Comment: I don't know of any hardware or software environment where the scenario you're describing would occur. In system with interrupt priorities, the same interrupt from the same device would have the same priority, and in the absence of hardware priorities software would block further interrupts from the device. Synchronization would be achieved either way by blocking other interrupts from the device until the ISR was finished.

Comment: Thanks, my example wasn't well suited, I changed it. Imagine using  e.g. an AURIX with 128 interrupts and timer cells that are individually mapped to different interrupt priorities, and no OS. E.g. both ISRs may randomly write data to the ethernet chip and are not synced via any semaphor or anything else in software. Is ethernet built to handle that?

Comment: Yes it would fail. Writing data to an ethernet chip in multiple ISRs is asking for trouble.

Comment: It's very unlikely any sort of Ethernet device interface would support what you're suggesting, but strictly speaking it would depend on the particular implementation. Fundamentally Ethernet makes no requirement either way, it's just not the sort of thing any sort of hardware interface supports. Generally interrupts need to be disabled when accessing a hardware interface when it's possible for an ISR to access that interface.